# How to select multiple custom Firebase event parameters in BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I exported Firebase events to BigQuery and now I'm trying to select two parameters from a certain event. Here is the query for selecting one parameter:

```
select event_dim.params.value.int_value as level_id
from [com_company_appname_ANDROID.app_events_20161210]
where event_dim.name = "level_replays_until_first_victory" and  event_dim.params.key = "level_id"
```

Both parameters are int values, name of the first parameter is `level_id`, and the second parameter is `count`. What I would like is to show is `level_id` in first column and `count` in second column.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below will work with [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                                 WHERE params.key = 'level_id') AS level_id,
  (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                                 WHERE params.key = 'count') AS count
FROM `com_company_appname_ANDROID.app_events_20161210`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name  = 'level_replays_until_first_victory'
```

See also [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) in case if you are stuck with Legacy SQL

Comment: Now lets say I'd like to only show the rows, where the "count = 5", how would you formulate that in this case?

Comment: there are many ways. to make my reply fit into comment - just add to the very end of query next highlighted statement `AND (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params WHERE params.key = 'count') = 5`. if you have more questions - please do not use comments for asking  - rather please post new question and we will be happy to help

Answer (score 11):

I love the previous solution! Here is an alternative solution for the same problem I came up with. I'd welcome comments on which solution is more efficient/cheaper and why.

```
SELECT event_param1.value.int_value AS level_id, 
event_param2.value.int_value AS count
FROM `com_company_appname_ANDROID.app_events_20161210`,
UNNEST(event_dim) event,
UNNEST(event.params) as event_param1,
UNNEST(event.params) as event_param2
WHERE event.name = 'level_replays_until_first_victory'
AND event_param1.key = 'level_id'
AND event_param2.key = 'count'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I find quite handy is to use [User Defined Functions to analyze user properties and event parameters](https://robertsahlin.com/flatten-firebase-properties-and-parameters-in-bigquery/)

```
#Standard-SQL

#UDF for event parameters
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION paramValueByKey(k STRING, params ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64 >>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(params) x WHERE x.key=k)
);

#UDF for user properties
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION propertyValueByKey(k STRING, properties ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64>, set_timestamp_usec INT64, index INT64 > >>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value.value FROM UNNEST(properties) x WHERE x.key=k)
);

#Query the sample dataset, unnesting the events and turn 'api_version', 'round' and 'type_of_game' into columns 
SELECT 
  user_dim.user_id,
  event.name,
  propertyValueByKey('api_version', user_dim.user_properties).string_value AS api_version,
 paramValueByKey('round', event.params).int_value as round,
 paramValueByKey('type_of_game', event.params).string_value as type_of_game
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.android_dataset.app_events_20160607`,
UNNEST(event_dim) as event
WHERE event.name = 'round_completed'
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

An update to the second solution

```
SELECT 
    event_param1.value.int_value AS level_id, 
    event_param2.value.int_value AS count
FROM 
   `com_company_appname_ANDROID.app_events_20161210`,
UNNEST(event_params) as event_param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as event_param2
WHERE event_name = 'level_replays_until_first_victory'
AND
   event_param1.key = 'level_id' 
AND
   event_param2.key = 'count'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).