# BigQuery & Firebase - Sum event Value based on Key

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

In my android app, I'm logging the number of items selected by the user as the following

```
public static void trackItemsSelectedCount(Context context, int count) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("count", count);
    getAnalytics(context).logEvent("items_selected", bundle);
}
```

In BigQuery, I'm able to count the number of entries having the event `items_selected` as followed

```
SELECT event_dim.name as event,
COUNT(event_dim.name) as event_count
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(package_ANDROID.app_events_intraday_, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
where event_dim.name contains 'items_selected'
GROUP BY event
ORDER BY event DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I would like to get the SUM of `event_dim.params.value.int_value` having `count` as for `event_dim.params.key`

So far I'm doing the following, but that might not be accurate (as `event_dim.params.key` is not appearing anywhere). Any idea for more precise query would be appreciated :

```
SELECT event_dim.name as event,
COUNT(event_dim.name) as event_count ,
COUNT(event_dim.params.value.int_value) as value_count
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(package_ANDROID.app_events_intraday_, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
where event_dim.name contains 'items_selected'
GROUP BY event
ORDER BY event DESC LIMIT 1;
```

## Answer

```
SELECT 
    SUM((SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params WHERE params.key = 'count')) AS count 
FROM package_ANDROID.app_events_20170123, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name = 'items_selected'
```

Comment: Have you read the similar past questions, such as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090396/how-to-select-multiple-custom-firebase-event-parameters-in-bigquery

Comment: I haven't found this one. Thanks. After investigation, I came up with the following query : `SELECT 
  SUM((SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                                 WHERE params.key = 'count')) AS count
FROM package_ANDROID.app_events_20170123, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name  = 'items_selected'`

Comment: Great! You might want to post it as an answer to your question so that other people can find the solution more easily.

Comment: The answer still has to be validated but I'm adding it to the answer in the meantime. cheers

Comment: @TurhanTech - you should put your answer as an actual answer  - not just as an update to your Question. This is allowed and is considered Ok on SO, unless of course you have already better answer(s) in place. Even more  - if your answer is the best out of al answers on your question  - you can accept it (you cannot vote your own answer though) :o)

Comment: thanks @MikhailBerlyant . done :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM((SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params WHERE params.key = 'count')) AS count 
FROM package_ANDROID.app_events_20170123, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name = 'items_selected'
```

Comment: While this may be the right answer, it doesn't explain why it would work.